# Recommended High Voltage Supply Circuit

Tags: flyback

Are there any circuit template I could look into if I want to achieve the following specification stated below:

Input: 5VDC
Output: 1kV, 0.5mA

I was looking into the flyback convertor but I am not sure if it will work out. Please help me out.

Comment: Have a look at [this article](http://www.edn.com/design/power-management/4334168/1-kV-power-supply-produces-a-continuous-arc).  First stage is a flyback, which generates 333V.  Second stage consists of 3 diode-capacitor voltage doublers.

Comment: @JImDearden Suggesting someone google it is counterproductive on SE. Our goal is to be the answer you get when googling. Opening that to find the answer is googling it is an infinite loop that could destroy the internet.

Comment: @Kortuk Not sure why this comment on this question but I would normally give a full answer if (a) its **not a homework question** and (b) there **is evidence the questioner has done some groundwork/basic research**. In the case of the question you're referring to I think both points apply. I really don't think its a good idea to encourage folk on SE to be lazy and expect us to just answer their homework because they can't or won't do a very basic search on google or some of the related questions and answers on SE.

Comment: @JImDearden that is what the downvote button on a question is for, it is "This question does not show any research effor; it is unclear or useful". If you feel it is too broad you can vote to close. If you dont want to answer you dont have to. If you would like to discuss further go to meta.

Answer (score 1):

For your power output of 0.5W fly-back is probably the best topology. Here's a circuit of one that uses 6V in to produce 300V out. It wouldn't surprise me if, with suitable changes to the transformer secondary, 1000V dc is producable: -

[image]

Linear Technology make many types of power converters so a deeper look into their offerings will probably yield something that fits the bill perfectly.